# How do i sort this array so that each category is sorted by ordernum?

Tags: php, sorting

I got a console based site and i cannot figure out how I can sort this data using the `$consoleORDER` value.

Basicly i am trying to make it so that each category is sorted by the `ordernum`.

EDIT: ok sorry for the lack of detail forgot that none are seeing the actually code execpt me lol.

```
$dispConsoleFeatures = "";
$consoleAdmin        = "";
$consoleStaff        = "";
$consoleAccount      = "";
$consoleMember       = "";
$consoleNews         = "";
$consoleRecruitment  = "";
$consoleSecurity     = "";
$consoleDivision     = "";
$consoleTourny       = "";
$consoleTraining     = "";
$consoleAwards       = "";
$consoleInfo         = "";
$consoleUnknown      = "";
$memConsole          = getMemberInfo("console_options", $membername);
$ConsoleIDs          = explode("[sep]", $memConsole);



foreach($ConsoleIDs as $console) {
    $consoleORDER         = getConsoleInfo2("ordernum", $console);
    $consoleLINK          = getConsoleInfo2("id", $console);
    $consoleNAME          = getConsoleInfo2("displayname", $console);
    $consoleHIDE          = getConsoleInfo2("hide", $console);
    $consoleCATEGORY      = getConsoleInfo2("category", $console);
    $consoleAdmin_I       = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/admin.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleStaff_I       = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/staff.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleAccount_I     = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/account.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleMember_I      = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/member.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleNews_I        = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/news.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleRecruitment_I = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/recruitment.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleSecurity_I    = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/security.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleDivision_I    = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/division.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleTourny_I      = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/tourny.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleTraining_I    = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/training.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleAwards_I      = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/awards.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleInfo_I        = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/info.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleUnknown_I     = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/unknown.png'><br></td></tr>";

    if($console != "" AND $consoleHIDE == "0") {

        if($consoleCATEGORY == "1") {
            $consoleAdmin .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat1 = "$consoleAdmin_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleAdmin</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "2") {
            $consoleMember .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat2 = "$consoleMember_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleMember</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "3") {
            $consoleAccount .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat3 = "$consoleAccount_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleAccount</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "4") {
            $consoleStaff .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat4 = "$consoleStaff_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleStaff</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleNews == "5") {
            $consoleNews .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat5 = "$consoleNews_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleNews</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "7") {
            $consoleDivision .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat7 = "$consoleDivision_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleDivision</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "8") {
            $consoleTourny .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat8 = "$consoleTourny_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleTourny</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "9") {
            $consoleNews .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat9 = "$consoleNews_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleNews</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "10") {
            $consoleAwards .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat10 = "$consoleAwards_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleAwards</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "11") {
            $consoleSecurity .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat11 = "$consoleSecurity_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleSecurity</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "12") {
            $consoleRecruitment .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat12 = "$consoleRecruitment_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleRecruitment</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "14") {
            $consoleTraining .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat14 = "$consoleTraining_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleTraining</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "15") {
            $consoleUnknown .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat15 = "$consoleUnknown_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleUnknown</td></tr>";
        } elseif($consoleCATEGORY == "16") {
            $consoleInfo .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat16 = "$consoleInfo_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleInfo</td></tr>";
        }


        $dispConsoleFeatures = "<tr><td class='main' align='center'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/console.png'><br></td></tr>$dispCat1$dispCat4$dispCat2$dispCat11$dispCat12$dispCat10$dispCat14$dispCat8$dispCat9$dispCat5$dispCat7$dispCat3<br>$dispCat16<br>$dispCat15";
    }
}
```

The end result of this is:

apprently i am not allowed to post with pictures yet. kinda annoying. so i uploaded tyhe image here.

http://www.swfclan.com/snippet1.jpg

As you see under "Tournament" it is ordered wrong because i never thought how it was ordered till i started rearranging them. The problem is the order is suppose to be (from top to bottom) Enter A Tournament, Create a Tournament, add tournament staff, delete tournament staff, tournament options.

Varaible $memConsole is pulled from a members data and each one is a number and it uses that number to retrieve the rest of the info.

Comment: It is hard to understand the strucutre of your data given that code example.  It looks like you want to sort `$ConsoleIDs`, but I cannot derive it's structure in order to see how it might be sorted.  can you just get rid of your code snippet and post a var_dump (or a portion of one) so that the actual array structure can be seen?

Comment: This code is very repetitive. You should try to refactor it down perhaps using arrays.

Comment: i won't let me add pictures yet so i edited the post and added the image to my website.

Comment: i thought about using sort() but i cannot figure out how to sort the array generated by the array.

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeBrant mentioned in the comments, it is hard to get a grasp on the structure with the code provided. But I did attempt to do so. I put everything into an array with `ordernum` as the `key` and then used `ksort` to order. You might have to play around with it a bit.

Also I changed your `if-elseif` to `swicth` statments, a matter of personal preference, easier to read:

**Note:** I commented out your functions and changed your `foreach` for testing purposes.

```
$orderNum = array(1, 99, 15);
$i = 0;
foreach($orderNum as $oNum) {
    //$consoleORDER = getConsoleInfo2("ordernum", $console);
    $consoleORDER = $oNum;
    //$consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['LINK'] = getConsoleInfo2("id", $console);
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['LINK'] = "Link";
    //$consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['NAME'] = getConsoleInfo2("displayname", $console);
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['NAME'] = "name";
    //$consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['HIDE'] = getConsoleInfo2("hide", $console);
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['HIDE'] = "hide";
    //$consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['CATEGORY'] = getConsoleInfo2("category", $console);
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['CATEGORY'] = "category";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Admin_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/admin.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Staff_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/staff.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Account_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/account.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Member_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/member.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['News_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/news.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Recruitment_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/recruitment.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Security_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/security.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Division_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/division.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Tourny_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/tourny.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Training_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/training.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Awards_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/awards.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Info_I'] = "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/info.png'><br></td></tr>";
    $consoleArray['orderNum'][$consoleORDER]['Unknown_I']= "<tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/unknown.png'><br></td></tr>";

    ####################################################################
    ## OTHER THAN THE CASE-SWITCH I DID NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING CODE ##
    ####################################################################
    if($console != "" && $consoleHIDE == "0") {
        switch ($consoleCATEGORY) {
        case "1":
            $consoleAdmin .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat1 = "$consoleAdmin_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleAdmin</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "2":
            $consoleMember .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat2 = "$consoleMember_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleMember</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "3":
            $consoleAccount .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat3 = "$consoleAccount_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleAccount</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "4":
            $consoleStaff .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat4 = "$consoleStaff_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleStaff</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "5":
            $consoleNews .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat5 = "$consoleNews_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleNews</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "6":
            // Missing 6
            break;
        case "7":
            $consoleDivision .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat7 = "$consoleDivision_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleDivision</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "8":
            $consoleTourny .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat8 = "$consoleTourny_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleTourny</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "9":
            $consoleNews .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat9 = "$consoleNews_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleNews</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "10":
            $consoleAwards .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat10 = "$consoleAwards_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleAwards</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "11":
            $consoleSecurity .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat11 = "$consoleSecurity_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleSecurity</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "12":
            $consoleRecruitment .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat12 = "$consoleRecruitment_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleRecruitment</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "13":
            // Missing 13
            break;
        case "14":
            $consoleTraining .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat14 = "$consoleTraining_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleTraining</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "15":
            $consoleUnknown .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat15 = "$consoleUnknown_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleUnknown</td></tr>";
            break;
        case "16":
            $consoleInfo .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='console.php?pid=$consoleLINK'>$consoleNAME</a><br>";
            $dispCat16 = "$consoleInfo_I<tr><td class='main' align='left'>$consoleInfo</td></tr>";
            break;
        }
        $dispConsoleFeatures = "<tr><td class='main' align='center'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/console.png'><br></td></tr>$dispCat1$dispCat4$dispCat2$dispCat11$dispCat12$dispCat10$dispCat14$dispCat8$dispCat9$dispCat5$dispCat7$dispCat3<br>$dispCat16<br>$dispCat15";
    }
    $i++;
}
ksort($consoleArray['orderNum']);
echo '<pre>', print_r($consoleArray, true), '</pre>';
```

---

**Ouput:**

```
Array
(
    [orderNum] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LINK] => Link
                    [NAME] => name
                    [HIDE] => hide
                    [CATEGORY] => category
                    [Admin_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/admin.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Staff_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/staff.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Account_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/account.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Member_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/member.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [News_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/news.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Recruitment_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/recruitment.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Security_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/security.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Division_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/division.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Tourny_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/tourny.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Training_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/training.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Awards_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/awards.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Info_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/info.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Unknown_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/unknown.png'><br></td></tr>
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [LINK] => Link
                    [NAME] => name
                    [HIDE] => hide
                    [CATEGORY] => category
                    [Admin_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/admin.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Staff_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/staff.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Account_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/account.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Member_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/member.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [News_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/news.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Recruitment_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/recruitment.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Security_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/security.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Division_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/division.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Tourny_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/tourny.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Training_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/training.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Awards_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/awards.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Info_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/info.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Unknown_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/unknown.png'><br></td></tr>
                )

            [99] => Array
                (
                    [LINK] => Link
                    [NAME] => name
                    [HIDE] => hide
                    [CATEGORY] => category
                    [Admin_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/admin.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Staff_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/staff.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Account_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/account.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Member_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/member.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [News_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/news.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Recruitment_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/recruitment.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Security_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/security.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Division_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/division.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Tourny_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/tourny.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Training_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/training.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Awards_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/awards.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Info_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/info.png'><br></td></tr>
                    [Unknown_I] => <tr><td align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/console/unknown.png'><br></td></tr>
                )

        )

)
```

Is this close to what you are looking for?